Async redirection Node.JS, NO AJAX
I've searched for this question for days and already asked it, but everything I've done hasn't helped. When I'm redirecting from a POST request in node, nothing happens in the browser.
My app is configured like this:
./
 config/

   dbConnections.js

 controller/

   accountsController.js

   userController.js

 middleware/

   validateToken.js

 models/

   movieModel.js

   userModel.js

 public/

   index.html

   userpage.html

 routes/

   accounts.js

   users.js

 .env

I'm redirecting from this function in controller/userController.js :
const login = asyncHandler (async (req, res) => {
    const {email, password} = req.body;
    if (!email || !password){
        res.status(400);
        throw new Error("Email or password not provided");
    }
    const user = await User.findOne({email});
    if (user && (await bcrypt.compare(password, user.password))) {
        const accessToken = jwt.sign({
            user: {
                username: user.id,
                email: user.email,
                id: user.id
            },
        }, process.env.ACCESS_TOKEN_SECRET,
        {expiresIn: "30m"});
        console.log("Logged in!");
        res.redirect(302, "/home/userPAGE");
    }
    else {
        res.status(400);
        throw new Error("Email or Password is not valid");
    }

});

It just checks a user login, similar to other posts here, but it is also async which I thought is maybe why it's not working at this point.
In index.js is where the function I'm redirecting to is.
index.js:
const express = require("express");
const app = express();
const dotenv = require("dotenv").config();
const port = process.env.PORT;
const path = require("path");
const http = require('http');
var engine = require('consolidate');
const ejs = require('ejs');
const mustache = require('mustache');
const fs = require('fs');
const db = require("./config/dbConnection.js");
db();
app.set('views', __dirname + '/views');
app.engine('html', engine.mustache);
app.set('view engine', 'html');
app.use(express.json());
app.use("/home/users", require("./routes/users"));
app.use("/home/user", require("./routes/accounts.js"));
app.get("/home/userTEST", (req, res) => {
    res.status(200).sendFile(path.join(__dirname, "./views/index.html"));
});
app.get("/home/userPAGE", (req, res) => {
    console.log("HERE")
    res.render(path.join("userpage.html"));
});
app.listen(port, () =>{
    console.log(`Server running on port ${port}`);
});

This is a picture of what happens in the network tab.
I was also using sendFile before, but tried to use mustache to see if anything would change.
Lastly, when redirecting I start on the /home/userTEST path (in index.js) and call the login  function in the   section of javascript:

<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
    <label> Email <input type="text" class="email" id = "email"/> </label> <br/>
    <label> Password <input type="text" class="Password" id = "Password"/> </label> <br/>
    <button> Submit </button>
</body>

<script>
    var myEmail = document.querySelector(".email");
    var myPassword = document.querySelector(".Password")
    var button = document.querySelector("button")
    button.addEventListener("click", ()=>{
            var obj={
                email:myEmail.value,
                password:myPassword.value
            };
            fetch("/home/users/login", {
                method:"POST",
                headers:{
                    "Content-type":"application/json"
                },
                body:JSON.stringify(obj)
            })
    })
</script>
</html>


What stands out to me here is that you are using AJAX to make the form submission instead of using a form. Is there a reason for this? It would be far easier to use <form action="/home/users/login"> and skip all the JavaScript.
I suspect that the fetch happening on the front end is receiving the redirect, makes the GET request, but has no instructions on what to do with the response to the GET request (there is no .then() handler on your fetch). A <form> would know to redirect the browser there and load the page.

It tries to GET /users/login, but that's not a path I have right now (userTEST is a placeholder now), and I want to feed in the email and password into the function and redirect from there.

Based on that network tab screen shot, it looks like the GET is heading to userPAGE, which is the redirect from your login route in Node right?
You mentioned the browser is not doing anything, that's because I think the GET to userPAGE is just being recieved and ignored, since your AJAX request on the front end has no instructions on the fetch receipt.
If you want it to navigate to a new page upon receipt, you would have to add a .then() to the fetch promise and use JavaScript to navigate, or change to a classic <form> element and use the built in HTML way to navigate.

Ok, but without any javascript and only with , how do would I send the information to the backend (my login function).

<form> is designed explicitly for that purpose! https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/form
Make sure to include the method and action properties on the form container, add the type="submit" to your button, and name the two fields with the name property to define their property names.
On the backend you'll need to make a change to how the data is parsed, because it will come in as a different encoding from JSON (URL encoded), but will otherwise operate the same way and you'll access them through req.body.

Yeah, it finally worked, thanks a lot! Is there an advantage in redirecting with a javascript section?

Using <form> is more inline with the typical way the Web is expected to work. Sticking with the platform means typical assumptions that others have while using your app are going to be mostly right. For example, forms are more accessible if someone is using a screen reader, and also your app will work if JavaScript is disabled on a user's browser.
When you do it via JS, you are taking the wheel and have to manage all your behaviour/accessibility yourself, but you can customize it really precisely. For example, if you wanted it to redirect conditionally based on the response.
